# How to send data via POST method?

Tags: react-native

I just need a way to send data via POST method, but the response is empty. Why ?

**React Native code:**

```
fetch('http://justanexample.altervista.org/saveinfo.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({text: "blablabla", id_product: "12"})
}).then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseData) => { console.log("response: " + responseData); })
.catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

**Saveinfo.php:**

```
echo "Hello World\n";
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

**Response:**

```
response: Hello World
[]
```

Comment: use print_r() instead of echo. print_r(json_encode($_POST))

Comment: @Shaniawan Done, it returns: "response: Hello World
Array
(
)
1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your success handler you have to edit response.text() beacause you're getting a json response

```
fetch('http://justanexample.altervista.org/saveinfo.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
           },
  body: JSON.stringify({text: "blablabla", id_product: "12"})
})
.then((response) => JSON.stringify(response.json())) 
.then((responseData) => { console.log("response: " + responseData); })
.catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

In your php code use this instead of your existing code

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE)
echo $obj;
```

FormData Exemple :

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append({text: "blablabla", id_product: "12"});
body: data
```

Comment: Done, it returns an empty string: "response: "

Comment: Done, it returns this: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: try to edit JSON.stringify(response.json()) in then (response) if it dosn't work beacause your file is returning a html file then edit your php file to get values from $_REQUEST like your first file

Comment: Same problem. With the GET method it works. Only with the POST method it doesn't work.

Comment: did your tried to use formData ? i will put an exemple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142062/discussion-between-g-mansour-and-xrobot).

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake that *may* lead to an empty response is the missing `'Content-Length'` property in the headers object.

Try adding it like this:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({text: "blablabla", id_product: "12"})

fetch('http://justanexample.altervista.org/saveinfo.php', {
  method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
     'Accept': 'application/json', 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Content-Length': data.length 
    },
    body: body
}).then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => { console.log("response: " + responseData); })
  .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

and let me know if that helps.