# react-native make local json file

Tags: android, json, react-native

I want to make a local JSON file and want to post data there. I want to make an attendance system using react-native. I want to post data using react-native and data will post through Flatlist. Data will save me a JSON file created by me.
I have already made a JSON file

```
[{
    "Roll": 1101,
    "name": "Israt Jerin",
    "Status": "P"
},
{
    "Roll": 1102,
    "name": "Rifat Murtuza",
    "Status": "P"
},
{
    "Roll": 1103,
    "name": "Nabil Kaysar",
    "Status": "P"
}]
```

here I can access this file by using this code

```
 <FlatList
      data={data_local}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Text> {item.name}</Text>
          <Text> {item.Roll}</Text>

          <RadioForm
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={0}
            onPress={value => {
              this.setState({ value: value });
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
```

And this my Submit button

```
<Button
      title="Submit"
      onPress={() =>
        this.MyPost()
      }
    />
```

Here is the project Look Like
[image]

My question is I want to insert using this radiobutton and flatlist and insert into a json file

Comment: Your question is not clear - _My question is I want to insert using this radiobutton and flatlist and insert into a json file_

Comment: So you are done?

Answer (score -1):

You can manage this by two ways.

1. Take a new array in state and insert & delete item in that array accordingly.

`this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, 'new value'] }) //simple value
this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, ...[1,2,3] ] }) //another array`

1. You can set take a `selected` field in existing array. And change its value on click of Radio Button. And collect all selected fields when you need to post.

**I will prefer second way.**

**An example to prepare final json**

```
  prepareJson(){
      var json = {};
      json.image = this.state.image;
      var absent = [];
      var present = [];
      this.state.myArray.map(item => {
        if(item.Status == "P") present.push(item);  
        else absent.push(item);
      }
      json.absent = absent;
      json.present = present;
      return json;
  }
```

here is how you will change state array item value on change of Radio button.

```
 <FlatList
      data={this.state.data_local} // data should be rendered from state
      ...
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          ...
          <RadioForm
           ...
            onPress={value => {
              item.Status = value;
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

These changes will be in state always. So when you get array from state, you will get latest array for mapping.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489531/6891563) for posting data.

**Update**

This is how you define some array in state.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        array: [],
    };
}
```

If you want change state field, just call `setState()` like

```
this.setState({ array});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177776/discussion-on-answer-by-khemraj-react-native-make-local-json-file).

Comment: @khemraj I didn't find any solution and also I have tried with your logic to post data in Local JSON file all in vain still you have tried . I can post data using api not in Local json file . Anyway thanks Your logic still helps me .

Comment: @RifatMurtuza your question is too broad, You can ask something specific, On stackoverflow, you can ask some issues of code, but it is not a solution provider website.